# Switch is not render react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, render

I am trying check if has cookies (login) and redirect to /dashboard. I added a Switch on arround Route, but it is not render the component. If I remove Switch, the page dont load: *"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."*

My code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout.js';
import './Login.scss';

const Auth = () => (
   <Router>
     <div id="login" className="height100">
      <Switch>
         <Route  path="/" component={Login}/>
         <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Protected}/>
        </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router>
)

const fakeAuth = {
   isAuthenticated: false,
   authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
     setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
 }
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
   <Route {...rest} render={props => (
     fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
       <Redirect to={{
         pathname: '/',
         state: { from: props.location }
       }}/>
    )
   )}/>
)

const Protected = () => <Layout />

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
     redirectToReferrer: false
   }

 setCookie = (cname,cvalue,exdays) => {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60));
     var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
 }

 getCookie = (cname) => {
      var name = cname + "=";
     var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
     var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
     for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
             c = c.substring(1);
         }
         if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
             return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 // checkCookie() {
 //     var redirect = this.getCookie("redirectToReferrer");
 //     if (redirect) {
 //     } else {
 //         this.setCookie("redirectToReferrer", true, 30);
 //     }
 // }

  login = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const that = this;

  const data = {
   'username': this.username.value,
   'password': this.password.value
  }

  const checkLogin = function(e) {
   if(e.username === data.username && e.password === data.password) {
       fakeAuth.authenticate();
    that.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
    that.setCookie("redirectToReferrer", true, 30);
   } else {
    alert('fail');
   }
  }

  fetch('http://maiconfurtado.com.br/test.json').then(r => r.json())
   .then(e => checkLogin(e))
   .catch(e => alert(e.message));
   }

   render() {
     const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/dashboard' } };
     const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
     const redirect = this.getCookie("redirectToReferrer");

     if (redirectToReferrer || redirect) {
        return (
          <Redirect to={from} />
        )
     }

     return (
   <div className="box-login col-10 col-10-sm center-block">
    <form className="col-9 col-10-xs center-block" onSubmit={this.login}>
     <div className="input-group">
      <label htmlFor="username">E-mail</label>
      <input type="text" className="input" id="username" name="username" ref={node => this.username = node} required />
     </div>
     <div className="input-group">
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" className="input" id="password" name="password" ref={node => this.password = node} required />
     </div>
     <div className="input-group">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
     )
 }
}

export default Auth
```

I have another problem too: *Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/dashboard"*

Comment: Problem could come from here: const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/dashboard' } };
Since you are not using PropTypes how are you sure Login component is receiving that?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia i dont know, I just copied it from her: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: I suggeest to check Login component props with a console.log and see if it gets the right parameter in the right way

Answer (score 0):

Check if your answer is here [react-router by Tyler Mcginnis](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)